# Translate, rotate, and redefine origin of UIView simultaneously

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm making a game in UIView. I'm trying to simulate the way the iOS Maps app works, when the compass auto-map-orientation is enabled.
I have a UIView, and I'm trying to change the map's X & Y co-ordinates, its angle, and its center point (origin).
But I'm having some trouble getting my head around how to do it.
Here's what I'm trying to use:
(this code is inside a game loop)

```
//move map
CGRect oldFrame = mapView.frame;
oldFrame.origin.y += 1;
mapView.frame = oldFrame;
//rotate map
mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(mapAngle);
```

So, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Translation is the redefinition of the origin. What happens when you use this code, and why not include the translation in the transform instead of modifying the view's frame?